# AWS Cognito Hosted UI - Getting CORS error after redirection back to localhost

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement a very simple react app with an authorization/authentication flow by using Cognito Hosted UI. After a successful login operation Hosted UI redirects back to localhost:3000  with a CORS error. However, though I couldn't find any place to enable CORS from AWS Cognito side. Additionally, I am not sure if this about reactjs. I am a newbie on react and maybe I am mistaken about cognito. Here are the steps I am following;

- Open the Landing Page
- Click on Login which will open the Cognito Login Form
- Enter credentials to login
- Redirect back to localhost:3000

Here is `App.js` file

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Amplify, {Auth, Hub} from 'aws-amplify';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'us-east-1',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERPOOL_ID,

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERPOOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID,

        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: false,

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',

        // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
        oauth: {
            domain: 'https://***.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
            redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000',
            redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
            responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
        }
    }
});

function App(props) {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is Landing page</h1>
      <a href="https://foobar.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=3chm4jkbcn767oqu2m9icconcs&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000">Login</a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Landing Page

[image]

Cognito Hosted UI

[image]

And here is the error from developer console as well.

[image]

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was happening because of my configuration setup for Amplify's `oauth` part. I set domain to `https://***.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com` so that Amplify was adding another `https` prefix. Removing https from the domain made the trick. I totally missed this.

This is the correct setup for oauth part

```
oauth: {
    domain: '***.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
    redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000',
    redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
    responseType: 'code'
}
```